# How can you find $\int_0^8xf'(x)\,{\rm d}x$ when $f(8) = 9$ and $f(4+x) = -f(4-x)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

This is the actual question:

If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous differientable function and given that $f(8) = 9$ and $f(4+x) = -f(4-x)$, what is $\int_0^8xf'(x)$d$x$?

This is what I have thus far:

If $f(8) = 9$ and $f(4+x) = -f(4-x)$, then $-f(0) = 9 \Rightarrow f(0) = -9$.

Say $u = x$ and d$v = f'(x)$d$x$, then d$u = $d$x$ and $v=f(x)$.

So    $\int_0^8xf'(x)$d$x = \int_0^8u$d$v = uv|^8_0 - \int^8_0v$d$u. = (8\cdot9 - 0\cdot9) - F(x)|^8_0 = 72 - F(x)|^8_0$ (not sure if this is a correct notation). Since I don't know what $f$ is, I obviously don't know its integral either. What other way can I use to find the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I changed the title as it was not the same as the question body. The answer to the title as it was before is simply you can't. There is not enough information in just knowing $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ to be able to evaluate $\int_a^b xf'(x){\rm d}x$.

Comment: To solve it use integration by parts: $\int_0^8 xf'(x){\rm d}x = [xf(x)]_0^8 - \int_0^8 f(x){\rm d}x$ and try to use the $f(x+4) = -f(x-4)$ property to deduce the value of the last integral ($f$ is odd about $x=4$)

Comment: @Winther I see it now. The surface area between the $x$ axis and the function line between $0$ and $4$ is the opposite of the one between $4$ and $8$. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**.-$$\int_0^8 xf'(x){\rm d}x =\int_0^8 xd(f(x)= [xf(x)]_0^8 - \int_0^8 f(x){\rm d}x\\\int_0^8 xf'(x){\rm d}x=72-\int_0^8 f(x){\rm d}x$$ Now calculation gives $f(4)=0$ and because of $f(4+x) = -f(4-x)$ the function can be considered as being odd respect to the new origin $x=4$.

A realization of such a function is the straight line $$f(x)=9(\frac x4-1)$$ In this case we have $$\int_0^8 xf'(x){\rm d}x=72-\int_0^89(\frac x4-1)dx=72$$

It seems it could be other realizations of $f(x)$ according to the fact that $f$ odd respect of $x=4$ but always the answer will be $72$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f$ is odd with respect to the point $x=4$. We therefore replace $f$ with
$$g(x):=f(4+x)\ .$$
Then $$g(-x)= -g(x),\quad g(4)=9,\quad f(x)=g(x-4),\quad f'(x)=g'(x-4)\ .$$
It follows that
$$J:=\int_0^8 x f'(x)\>dx=\int_0^8 x g'(x-4)\>dx\ ,$$
and substituting $x:=4+t$ $(-4\leq t\leq 4)$ gives
$$J=\int_{-4}^4 (4+t) g'(t)\>dt=4\bigl(g(4)-g(-4)\bigr)+\int_{-4}^4 tg'(t)\>dt=72+0=72\ ,$$
since  $g$ is odd and $g'$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Notice that $$\int_0^8xf'(x)\,{\rm d}x=\int_0^8x\,{\rm d}f(x)=xf(x)\bigg|_0^8-\int_0^8 f(x)\,{\rm d}x,$$

where$$xf(x)\bigg|_0^8=8f(8)-0f(0)=72,$$

and 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^8 f(x)\,{\rm d}x&=\int_0^4 f(x)\,{\rm d}x+\int_4^8 f(x)\,{\rm d}x\\
&=\int_0^4 f(x)\,{\rm d}x+\int_{-4}^0 f(x+8)\,{\rm d}x\\
&=\int_0^4 f(x)\,{\rm d}x-\int_{-4}^0 f(-x)\,{\rm d}x\\
&=\int_0^4 f(x)\,{\rm d}x+\int_{4}^0 f(x)\,{\rm d}x\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
where we apply the fact $f(x+8)=-f(-x)$ and a series of variable substitution.

As a result,$$\int_0^8xf'(x)\,{\rm d}x=72-0=72.$$